# MySql ORDERBY & Limit -> wrong result

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query:

```
SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE post_type = 'person' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 8
```

I also build in a pagination so there are pages (1, 2, 3, ...) that show me the next 8 records

```
SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE post_type = 'person' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 8, 8
```

in the first query I got a person called "John Doe" and in the second query also but the person is just 1 time in the Database and another person that should appear there is not here... what is my problem?

I have to tell you, that I imported about 1K records from the old website in the new one and now i created a person and modified the post_data so this person should appear in the first or second page.

1. Page

   ```
   ---------------------------
   |Name          | post_date  |
   ---------------------------
   |John Doe      | 19.11.2016 |
   |Hans Mair     | 29.11.2016 |
   |Peter Gray    | 29.11.2016 |
   |Eric Test     | 27.11.2016 |
   |Peter Henny   | 21.11.2016 |
   |George Green  | 19.11.2016 |
   |Susan White   | 19.11.2016 |
   |Barbara Gnome | 19.11.2016 |
   ---------------------------
   ```
2. Page

   ```
   -----------------------------
   |Name           | post_date    |
   -----------------------------
   |Simon Blue     | 19.11.2016   |
   |Garry Red      | 19.11.2016   |
   |Martin yellow  | 19.11.2016   |
   |Mattwo Brown   | 18.11.2016   |
   |Simon Bank     | 14.11.2016   |
   |Christian Rock | 12.11.2016   |
   |Walter White   | 12.11.2016   |
   |Homer Orange   | 12.11.2016   |
   -----------------------------
   ```

but in the 2. page Simon Blue doesn't appear instead there is again John doe

Comment: I dont see Jhon Doe in second page

Comment: try **ORDER BY post_date DESC,Name ASC** to sort the result if there are more then 1 equal date

Comment: Are you aware that `LIMIT 8,8` means _retrieve only 8 records starting from record # 9_, meaning, records 9 to 16?

Comment: @BerndBuffen Thanks this solved my problem!!!!